# expressjs session: determine how much time left in session without resetting to original maxAge val?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express-session

I'm dealing with an app that uses express-session in a node.js app.
https://github.com/expressjs/session

Session durations are being set with the `maxAge` property.

According to the documentation for [maxAge](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookiemaxage-1):

> Alternatively req.session.cookie.maxAge will return the time remaining
>   in milliseconds, which we may also re-assign a new value to adjust the
>   .expires property appropriately. The following are essentially
>   equivalent
>
> ```
> var hour = 3600000 
> req.session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + hour)
> req.session.cookie.maxAge = hour
> ```
>
> For example when maxAge is set to 60000 (one minute), and 30 seconds
>   has elapsed it will return 30000 until the current request has
>   completed, **at which time req.session.touch() is called to reset
>   req.session.cookie.maxAge to its original value** [*emph added by me*].

Essentially what I'm wondering: **is there is a way to know how long it is before a session will expire without simultaneously resetting the lifespan of the session?**

The end goal is to be able to give a prompt to the user just before the session expires. For example, you go on your banking site, and they'll give you a dialog saying your session is about to expire, with option to keep alive; if ignored, then you are re-directed to the logout page.